# Android Inject System Activity Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm building a feature about allowing user to select the ext directory to save file in android 5.0. Below is my code.

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private void triggerStorageAccessFramework() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_STORAGE_ACCESS);
}
```

The problem is I want to force user to select the directory in the popup show up. For now, user can press back button or select outside the popup to close it. I want to prevent it. Because this is the system activity, so I cannot make this as usual activity.

Can anyone give me a way to achieve this. Thanks all for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible, but you can do one thing, if this doesn't select any file, you can again show the dialog till the user selects any file.

Comment: Thanks Patro for quick reply me. Your suggestion will be the lastest choice if we cannot have a better one.